Required scope doesn't exist error caused for oneNote Business account user
I use oneNote api in my chrome extension oneClipper
Business account users cannot grant access in oAuth flow.
Error: Notes.Create,Notes.ReadWrite,wl.offline_access scope doesn't exist on the resource.
User Account type: Business account
The application 'oneClipper' asked for scope 'Notes.Create,Notes.ReadWrite,Notes.ReadWrite.All,wl.offline_access' that
doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Contact the app vendor. 
Trace ID: d88883f6-2ee4-4f0d-94ef-923ae0da1a00 Correlation ID: af486929-64ce-4f9c-b306-175cce4d49d8 Timestamp: 2024-10-09 12:52:27Z#

Many users report error on extension's github page. Github issue
How to fix this issue ??
please help
